# How to move Root nodes up and down in a treeview Access/VBA

Tags: ms-access, treeview, vba, nodes

Ok. I've been working a lot on a treeview and I decided that it would be convenient to allow the users to move the nodes of the treeview up and down however they see fit. My structure is just a simple two level treeview, however every root node must have a child. For example:

```
Root
  child
  child
  child
Root
  child
  child
Root
  child
  child
  child
  child
```

I have code written where you can only check off one box from the Root nodes at a time. What I want to do is click a button, and have the checked root node move up (or down) one position (of course taking its children with it).

The only way I can imagine this working would be to completely rebuild the node one level higher than it was previously. This seems like it would be far too time consuming when the nodes begin to have more children etc.

When I searched I found a ton of C# results, but since I'm using VBA it didn't help me at all. If anybody has any suggestions outside of rebuilding the entire node I would love to hear it. Thanks

Comment: I saw this and wondered if it might help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209898

Comment: Can you show your table structure? Also, I think rebuilding the node is actually a good idea depending on how you are using this table/records. Will there be hundreds and thousands of records? Will they change frequently? If you answered yes to both, then, yeah, it probably won't be feasible to rebuild. Otherwise I think rebuilding the whole thing is the right solution.

Comment: @Remou- That drag and drop example is cool (I've seen it before) but from what I gather they are switching node parents as opposed to switching the order of the root nodes.

Comment: @HK1- I guess I'll just rebuild the nodes then! I guess I was hoping there was a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was by saving the keys and text of my nodes in temporary variables, clearing the keys, and then switching them.

At this point, I then loop through all of the children and add them into an array of Nodes. I set the nodes.Parent property of each of them to the opposing node, and then it was all pretty much done.

This is possible because the data in the table depends on how the user structures the treeview, so once they have the treeview displaying how they want it, I can save the information I need and rebuild it when they open that particular record back up. I hope this is clear but I have some code chunks below to help clear this up.

```
 Private Sub MoveUP()
 Dim n As Node
 Dim key1 As String
'etc.....

 key1 = n.Key
 text1 = n.Text
 key2 = n.Previous.Key
 text2 = n.Previous.Text

'We have to clear out the keys now.
 n.Key = ""
 n.Previous.Key = ""

'Now replace the keys
 n.Key = key2
 n.Text = text2
 n.Previous.Key = key1
 n.Previous.Text = text1

 Call SwitchParents(n, n.Previous)
 End Sub
```

^The code above is made to move n up into n.Previous spot
The following code, is to switch the children of the nodes (if any)

```
 Private Sub SwitchParents(n1 As Node, n2 As Node)
 Dim nds1() As Node 'Declare with no size to ReDim later
 Dim nds2() As Node
 Dim c As Node 'this is the child node we will use to push into the array
 Dim i As Integer 

 i = n1.Children
 ReDim nds1(0 To i)
 Set c = n1.Child
 'Notice in both loops that i remains the number of children, the arrays fill backwards
 'because when you reassign the nodes.Parent property, the node jumps to the beginning,
 'so we pack them backwards and they come out displaying the same way they did before.
 Do While Not (c Is Nothing)
   i = i - 1
   Set nds1(i) = c
   Set c = c.Next
 Loop

 i = n2.Children
 ReDim nds2(0 To i)
 Set c = n2.Child
 Do While Not (c Is Nothing)
   i = i - 1
   Set nds2(i) = c
   Set c = c.Next
Loop

If Not IsEmpty(nds1()) Then
  For i = 0 To UBound(nds1()) - 1
    Set nds1(i).Parent = n2
  Next i
End If

If Not IsEmpty(nds2()) Then
  For i = 0 To UBound(nds2()) - 1
    Set nds2(i).Parent = n1
  Next i
End If
End Sub
```

I hope this example will help anybody else who has a similar two level tree structure and is looking to do something like this. I am doing it on a button click, however it could be reworked for a drag and drop method.